# How to make my banner (logo image) position on the center

Tags: headers, header-image

I'm trying to redesign my website, and I'm not sure how to make the banner (logo image) positioned on the center of the website. I tried editing the CSS of the theme to set it do display: flex and the justify-content: center and align-items: center however this didn't work. The theme I'm using is Lectura Lite. I tried searching on the web, however I couldn't find anything useful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is your html structure, but have you tried applying the css to the parent element of the header? Can you elaborate your question, or maybe try the css below:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```